# How to use Rocksdb merge in Java？

Tags: rocksdb, rocksdb-java

The documentation is not clear about how to use the merge operation while using rocksdb-jni, and I am not familiar with C++ API, how could I define an merge operator?

Answer (score 0):

You can't define new merge operators in java. They need to be implemented in C++ and then compiled and brought in Java

Eg how to use the built in uint64add operator `val options = Options().setMergeOperator(UInt64AddOperator())`

and then you can use `rocksDB.merge(keyByteArray, longValueByteArray)`